# $N>2$ gravitating masses can never reach equilibrium

Tags: statistical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, equilibrium

If you have $N>2$ point masses, each attracted to each other by the force of gravity, how could you go about showing that they will never reach equilibrium?

Comment: Define "equilibrium". There exist stable three-body systems.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're actually asking how you prove that the motion is chaotic rather than periodic. If so, the answer is with great difficulty!

The three body problem was solved by Karl Sundman in 1909, but the n-body problem was only solved in 1991 by Qiudong Wang$^1$. I say *solved* but atually both proofs really only showed the motion could be described by a polynomial expansion that was (mostly) convergent. In practice the polynomial description converges far too slowly to be useful.

$^1$ Wang Q. D., Celestial Mech and Dyn. Astron., 50, 73-88, 1991

Answer (score 1):

You should define equilibrium, however I believe you are talking about thermal equilibrium.  The answer is because gravitationally bound systems have a negative heat capacity.

The reason is as you add energy to a gravitationally bound system, the bodies move farther apart to increase potential energy, and slow down!  They lose kinetic to potential!

The key is the virial theorem, Kinetic Energy = - potential energy/2, written more compactly as K = -V/2.  Most places call T average kinetic energy, but I do not want to confuse it with temperature.  Virial theorem applies for particles with gravitational forces only between them, and can be generalized to other potentials.

Now E = K + V, by conservation of energy.  Substitute the virial theorem into E:

E = K - 2K = -K.  Now, lets use equipartition theorem.

E=-K=-3/2NkT

Notice how as temperature increases, energy decreases!

Now this argument has flaws, but the point is to remember that as we add energy, kinetic energy decreases.  You can see this more simply by solving the 2 body problem and adding energy.  The masses will move apart and slow down.

Now imagine dividing the system into small imaginary partitions.  If there is heat flow between two neighbouring partitions, the partition gaining energy would decrease in temperature, and the system losing energy would increase in temperature!  This would increase the size of the temperature gradient. For this reason it cannot equilibrate.

For more info, look at the paper "On the negative specific heat paradox" by Lynden-Bell.  It shows up free on google.

Comment: why would you apply a formula that is deduced from *ideal gas theory* to a system that is not freely moving due to attractive forces?

Comment: A good point though, and maybe it is what the OP is thinking about.